# Oracle Text error: DRG-10599: the colum is not indexed

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT
    c.ID AS "REFERENCIA",
    c.CIF_NIF AS "CIF",
    c.NUMERO_COMERCIO AS "COMERCIO",
    CASE
        WHEN c.RIESGO_REPUTACIONAL = 1 THEN 'Anexo 2B'
        WHEN c.RIESGO_REPUTACIONAL = 3 THEN 'Anexo 2A'
    END AS "RIESGO REPUTACIONAL",
    tp.NOMBRE AS "TECNOLOGIA",
    c.FECHA_INSERCION AS "FECHA CONTRATO",
    CASE
        WHEN av.FECHA_INSERCION IS NOT NULL THEN TO_CHAR(av.FECHA_INSERCION, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
        ELSE 'No se ha validado todavía'
    END AS "FECHA VALIDACION",
    c.DENOMINACION_COMERCIAL_TICKET AS "DENOMINACION COMERCIAL",
    c.COD_SECTOR_ACTIVIDAD_VISAMC AS "CAI",
    (SELECT c2.CODIGO FROM CNAE c2 WHERE CONTAINS(c2.LISTA_CAIS, c.COD_SECTOR_ACTIVIDAD_VISAMC, 1) > 0)
FROM
    CONTRATO c
LEFT JOIN ANRI_VALORACION av ON
    av.ID_CONTRATO = c.ID
INNER JOIN PRODUCTO p ON
    c.ID_PRODUCTO = p.ID
INNER JOIN REL_PRODUCTO_TIPOPRODUCTO rpt ON
    rpt.ID_PRODUCTO = p.ID
INNER JOIN TIPO_PRODUCTO tp ON
    tp.ID = rpt.ID_TIPO_PRODUCTO
WHERE
    c.RIESGO_REPUTACIONAL IN (1, 3)
    AND c.ESTADO = 'CONTRATO'
    AND TO_DATE(c.FECHA_INSERCION) >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-1)
ORDER BY c.FECHA_INSERCION,c.ID ASC
```

So here, it's failing my query and it's throwing an error like the column is not indexed in the line     `(SELECT c2.CODIGO FROM CNAE c2 WHERE CONTAINS(c2.LISTA_CAIS, c.COD_SECTOR_ACTIVIDAD_VISAMC, 1) > 0)` . My query is in Oracle, what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you'll have to create index as

```
create index i1_cnae_lista on cnae (lista_cais) indextype is ctxsys.context;
```

---

On the other hand, maybe you don't want to use Oracle Text. Is `contains` intentional, or ...?

Because, if you don't need Oracle Text, maybe something like this would do (i.e. the `INSTR` function):

```
SELECT c2.CODIGO FROM CNAE c2 
WHERE INSTR (c2.LISTA_CAIS, c.COD_SECTOR_ACTIVIDAD_VISAMC) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

"CONTAINS(c2.LISTA_CAIS" means there has to be a *domain* index defined on the LISTA_CAIS column.

Query ALL_INDEXES for TABLE_NAME = 'CNAE' (assuming that is a table, not a view or synonym) to find the indexes for that table. This also tells you the index type which will tell if you it is a Text (domain) index.

Then query ALL_IND_COLUMNS for those indexes to see what columns that the index is defined for.